What is the default layout behavior of a <figure> with an <img>?
My question intends to understand the concept behind. In the end I would like to center an <img> (the purple square in the example belowe) inside of a <figure>. There are several solutions out there. But I don't understand them well. What I need to understand first is how a figure really works. I assuming this would make it more easier to validate the solutions out there.
Example code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body style="background-color: yellow;">
    <figure style="background-color: green;">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEgAAABICAIAA
        ADajyQQAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAEnQAABJ0Ad
        5mH3gAAABnSURBVGhD7c8BDQAgDMAw7F0nF4qOkiU10HNnv1RMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0x
        TTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNMU0xTTFNM
        U0zzaWz2AU8XpdIsmIu3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
    </figure>
</body>
</html>

The rendered result:

What I understand is that the figure (green box) use the full width by default. That is fine for me. So it won't make sense to center the figure. To my understanding I need to center the image inside of the figure.

Please keep the MWE as minimal as possible. Don't edit it and make it more complex with separating the CSS content.

I appreciate why you might feel that way, but having it as an interactive snippet means we can use our browsers' devtools with it directly to experiment - so there are advantages to my edit, but I'll respect your right to sovereignty over your posts. (the downvote is not mine, btw)

the <figure> element is by default a block level element with margins set. As that it it occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent element. To see the browser defaults just inspect the page and see the element style given by its type

And it is not possible to align elements in a block level layout?

It is possible to align elements in block-level elements. All the websites out there within nesting elements have these behaviours. In fact flexboxes, grids etc all work on this foundational principle :)

You need to understand the foundational behaviour of HTML elements.
They can be inline(like img, a etc) or block level (div, section, figure etc)
The <figure> is a block-level element, and it is usually used to group media  elements like images, diagrams, or illustrations with a caption.

By default, block-level elements take up the full width of their
parent container.

<img> on the on the other hand is an inline-element and takes the width of the content (which for img is image width & height)
Now to center any element (with given width & height), be it inline or block level within a parent element, we can use CSS. And there are so many ways to do this.

Using flexbox:
figure {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh; /* This is to show centering vertically as well */
    margin: 0; /* Reset default margin */
}


Using text-align:center;  for simple cases
figure {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0; /* Reset default margin */
}



There are other ways, which I would suggest you to do an R&D about like CSS-Grids, margin:0 auto; etc etc
